# CSS; images and text, float

Tags: css

Very new to CSS, so apologies if this is simple beyond belief.

I am currently working on a page for class. There is a section where icons (coffee, music notes, food and a waiter) need to be floated above their respective headings. I have tried floating and clearing various elements. I hope I am just overlooking something simple!

I cannot edit the HTML in any way or I will receive a zero on the assignment, and I am only allowed to use CSS.

I am having trouble posting the code, so I hope it is okay to share the links.

HTML 
https://github.com/melonysmith/dws1/blob/gh-pages/DWS1-Practical/index.html

CSS
https://github.com/melonysmith/dws1/blob/gh-pages/DWS1-Practical/css/styles.css

Any and all help and suggestions are welcome and very much appreciated!

**EDIT: HTML and CSS posted.
I did get the icons to center above their headings, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the "promo" section to center to the rest of the page, including the icons, headers and paragraphs.**

```
<!-- begin promo -->
    <section id="promo">

        <div id="promo-first-col" class="promo-col">

             <h3 id="coffee">Imported Coffee</h3>

             <p>Checkout our various tyes of imported coffee.</p>               

        </div>

        <div class="promo-col">

             <h3 id="music">Great Music</h3> 

             <p>Our DJs will entertain you like never before.</p>               

        </div>

        <div class="promo-col">

             <h3 id="food">Finest Cuisine</h3>

             <p>From Italian to Tex-Mex, you will find all types of food</p>                

        </div>

        <div class="promo-col">

             <h3 id="service">Nice Staff</h3>

             <p>You will never forget our smile and professional attitude.      </p>                

        </div>

    </section>
    <!-- end promo -->



#promo {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
padding-bottom: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#promo p {
background-color: #fff;
width: 255px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}   

#promo h3 {
background-color: #fff;
width: 255px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 80px;
margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.promo-first-col {
display: inline-block;
background-color: #fff;
text-align: center;
width: 255px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.promo-col {
display: inline-block;
background-color: #fff;
text-align: center;
width: 255px;
margin:0 auto;
padding-top: 20px;
}   

#coffee {
float: left;
width: 255px;
background: #fff;
background-image: url("../images/ico_coffee.png");
background-position: center top; 
line-height: 25px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 30px;
float: left;
}           

#music {
float: left;
width: 255px;
background: #fff;
line-height: 25px;
background-image: url("../images/ico_music.png");
background-position: center top; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 30px;
float: left;  
}       

#food {
float: left;
width: 255px;
background: #fff;
line-height: 25px;
background-image: url("../images/ico_food.png");
background-position: center top; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
padding-right: 30px;
float: left;
}

#service {
float: left;
width: 255px;
background: #fff;
line-height: 25px;
background-image: url("../images/ico_service.png");
background-position: center top; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 30px;
float: left;
clear: both;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

EDIT 2: Going to try and attempt to post a snippet. I'm new here, forgive my awkwardness!

All of the images, headers and paragraphs should be next to each other in a line with the image above the heading and the heading above the paragraph. That part I have figured out. Might need more code to explain, but this entire "promo" div is sitting to the left of the rest of the page, which is centered.

```css
#promo {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
 
#promo p {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 255px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
} 

#promo h3 {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 255px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 80px;
 margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.promo-first-col {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 width: 255px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
 
.promo-col {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 width: 255px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-top: 20px;
} 
 
#coffee {
 float: left;
 width: 255px;
 background: #fff;
 background-image: url("http://melonysmith.github.io/dws/DWS1-Practical/images/ico_coffee.png");
 background-position: center top; 
 line-height: 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    float: left;
}   
 
#music {
 float: left;
 width: 255px;
 background: #fff;
 line-height: 25px;
 background-image: url("http://melonysmith.github.io/dws/DWS1-Practical/images/ico_music.png");
 background-position: center top; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    float: left;  
}  

#food {
 float: left;
 width: 255px;
 background: #fff;
 line-height: 25px;
 background-image: url("http://melonysmith.github.io/dws/DWS1-Practical/images/ico_food.png");
 background-position: center top; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 30px;
    float: left;
}

#service {
 float: left;
 width: 255px;
 background: #fff;
 line-height: 25px;
 background-image: url("http://melonysmith.github.io/dws/DWS1-Practical/images/ico_service.png");
 background-position: center top; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.clear {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!-- begin promo -->
  <section id="promo">
 
   <div id="promo-first-col" class="promo-col">

     <h3 id="coffee">Imported Coffee</h3>

     <p>Checkout our various tyes of imported coffee.</p>     

   </div>

   <div class="promo-col">

     <h3 id="music">Great Music</h3> 

     <p>Our DJs will entertain you like never before.</p>     

   </div>

   <div class="promo-col">

     <h3 id="food">Finest Cuisine</h3>

     <p>From Italian to Tex-Mex, you will find all types of food</p>    

   </div>

   <div class="promo-col">

     <h3 id="service">Nice Staff</h3>

     <p>You will never forget our smile and professional attitude.</p>    

   </div>

  </section>
  <!-- end promo -->
```

Comment: care to post an example?

Comment: Sure.  Here is the HTML:

Comment: Oops, hit enter on accident. Will post example.

Comment: no, i meant code snippet. You should see an option for it on the toolbar that appears in the ask/edit a question menu. In it, you can provide the HTML and CSS, and it will render it like it would appear on a website. It's very useful when trying to figure out what's wrong. It's much better than just looking at the source code for figuring out your problem.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry... newbie here!

Comment: You can see when you go full page in the snippet that everything is lined up on the left margin of the page, but I need all of it to be centered. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Check out my answer. Does that help Melony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two container divs: one containing the coffee div and the cuisine div, and the other containing the other two divs. Set the container on the left to

```
float: left;
```

and the other to

```
float: right;
```

There are now several ways you can go about this. One way would be to set both containers a

```
width: 50%
```

and for the contained two divs in each column/container

```
text-align: center;
```

OR

You  could simply give them the float properties and then set margin-left on the left one and margin-right on the right one, and play around with the margins a bit until you get them where you want them.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply! Thank you! Your answer really helped, and everything is just the way it needed to be! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @MelonySmith alright. If it answered your question please make sure to select the checkmark next to the question so that future viewers can see that this answered your question